# Sorry, you are not allowed to create posts as this user

Tags: wordpress, rest, vuejs2, contact-form-7, http-status-code-401

I am building Vue.js application with Wordpress and trying to implement simple contact form with help of Contact Form 7 plugin.

So I encountered this issue: when I click 'send' button I receive 'Sorry, you are not allowed to create posts as this user.' error message with redirect to http://mywebsite.com/wp-json/wp/v2/contacts#wpcf7-f11-o1

I don't have any any user authentication on my website and I don't need one...